# How to remove mold from Styrofoam ceiling tiles?

Tags: ceiling, mold

I've recently noticed, that there are some sort of (stains) on a ceiling in a bathroom. The ceiling is covered with Styrofoam tiles of square shape. I took a closer look and it seems to me that it could be mold that developed on these tiles due to high humidity.

Are there any ways to remove that mold without removing the Styrofoam tiles?

- Styrofoam - *native language (пенопласт)*

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your ceiling is Styrofoam?

Comment: It is nearly certain that the tiles are not styrofoam, as that is flammable. If they really are, they should be replaced with something less hazardous.

Comment: More likely the tiles are some wood product, if mold is growing on them. Styrofoam is plastic, and mold doesn't grow on plastic.

Comment: @Steven as far as google translate gives me it is styrofoam. The ceiling itself isn't, but tiles, that are glued, are. I can make a picture and add it if it would help.

Comment: @eugene a picture would help.  And if english is not your native language, what would you call it in your language?  Perhaps someone can provide a better translation.

Comment: Those look like traditional ceiling tiles that are usually made up of wood fibers, not Styrofoam

Comment: As far as I know, there is no wood in those tiles.

Comment: Wood fiber, not wood. They are called "acoustic ceiling tile" where I am and they are made from loosely pressed fiber. similar to the production of paper, just much thicker and less dense. Styrofoam is not an approved building material, except as insulation, anywhere in the world as far as I know.

Comment: Any suggestions thou?

Answer (score 1):

[in the UK] I've just bought some 'Ronseal 3 in 1 mould killer' spray from B&Q -- also available on Amazon -- which has worked well on my polystyrene ceiling tiles in the bathroom. These were quite mouldy in places (due to problems with my roof).

The spray worked really well (**and the spray mechanism was very effective** - giving a good-coverage fine mist spray rather than dribbling out (onto me) or producing a 'squirt' covering only a small area).

I didn't try to remove all the mould-discolouration from the tiles as I will be painting over them (which is an option if you don't wish to remove the tiles from the ceiling as suggested by some. I'd love to get rid of my crappy ceiling tiles but I know I'd regret it given the resulting mess and cost to make it good).